# State not updating to another view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am using this for saving user info in user defaults for user isRegsitered.

```
struct UserKeys {
    static let isUserRegistered = "isUserRegistered"
}
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T
    
    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
final class UserSettings: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    @UserDefault(UserKeys.isUserRegistered, defaultValue: false)
    var isUserRegistered: Bool {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

// The Popup Login window on Same Dashboard View.

```
struct PopUpWindow: View {
    @ObservedObject var userRepo = UserSettings()
 Button(action: {
                            // Dismiss the PopUp
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                                userRepo.isUserRegistered = true
                                show = false
                                hideKeyboard()
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Submit")
```

& further I am listing in DashBoardView View as -

```
struct DashBoardView: View {

    @ObservedObject var userRepo = UserSettings()

    private var content: some View {
        if !userRepo.isUserRegistered {
            return PopUpWindow(show: .constant(true)) .eraseToAnyView()
        }
// .. Other conditions ..
```

So basically I have popup with Login box so after submit I am trying to dismiss dialog & want to listen value `userRepo.isUserRegistered`

Answer (score 1):

By initializing `UserSettings` class independently in both `PopUpWindow` and `DashBoardView`, you are actually saying that each view is managing its own data, hence the two views are not sharing the same data.

You should not initialize your `UserSettings` class from the `PopUpWindow` view, but instead, pass an instance to from `DashBoardView`.
The code would look like this:

**PopUpWindow**

```
struct PopUpWindow: View {
    @ObservedObject var userRepo: UserSettings
    Button(action: {
           // Dismiss the PopUp
           withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
           userRepo.isUserRegistered = true
           show = false
           hideKeyboard()
           }
           }, label: {
           Text("Submit")
// .. Other conditions ..
```

and then :

**DashBoardView**

```
struct DashBoardView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userRepo = UserSettings()
    
    private var content: some View {
        if !userRepo.isUserRegistered {
            return PopUpWindow(userRepo: userRepo, show: .constant(true)) .eraseToAnyView()
        }
// .. Other conditions ..
```

Comment: Great but I am looking for `userRepo` to be change independently ..Perhaps I need to use Enviroment Object.

Comment: yeah, that is the way to go, with `EnviromentObject` you'll be able to update data without always having to pass an instance of your class everywhere.

Comment: Especially if you want to share/access those values from multiple views

Comment: Can you update your answer with environment ? I am pretty new in swiftUI.

Comment: Hey @Amit, I think the implementation may depend on the way the environment is used, Check out this article https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views